# Is a general smooth rescaling of a complete vector field itself complete?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

$\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\til}{\tilde}$
$\newcommand{\M}{M}$
$\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}$
$\newcommand{\brk}[1]{\left(#1\right)} $
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\renewcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}$

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $X \in \Ga(TM) $.
Assume $X$ is **complete**, i.e, the flow of $X$ is defined on whole $\mathbb{R} \times M$.

I wonder what happens to the flow when $X$ is multiplied by some real **positive** function  $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$. My guess is that the flow will still be defined for any time, and that it will be a reparametrization of the original flow. (i.e only the speed may change). In particular $fX$ will be complete.

> **Question:**
>   Is this guess correct? Does it hold for non-compact manifolds? (Note I assume anyway $X$ is complete)

**Update:** As shown by Travis, when $M$ is non-compact, the scaled field need not be complete. Of course, when $M$ is compact, than any vector field is complete.

For the compact case, I am still interested to know if there is
a **global** smoothly changing reparametrization $h:\mathbb{R} \times M \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $\psi(t,p)=\phi(h(t,p),p) \forall t \in \mathbb{R} , p \in M$?

My analysis (below) shows that if there is such a reparametrization than it's **unique** (since it's enough to prove uniqueness locally), but I do not know how to show there exists such a global $h$.

(See my analysis for details about where my "procedure" gets stuck).

---

**My analysis so far:**

Let $\phi_p(t)=\phi(t,p)$ denote the $t$-time flow of $X$ from $p \in M$, i.e

$(1)\,\, \phi: \R \times M \to M \, , \, \dot \phi_p(t)=X(\phi_p(t))$

Take $Y = fX$. Denote the flow of $Y$ by $\psi_p(t)$. Assume there exists a real function $h_p:\R \to \R$ such that $\psi_p(t)=\phi_p(h_p(t))$.

Then $\dot \psi_p(t)=Y(\psi_p(t)) \Rightarrow \dot \phi_p(h_p(t))\cdot h_p'(t)=f(\psi_p(t)) \cdot X(\psi_p(t))$

So by $(1)$ we get: $$X(\psi_p(t)) \cdot h_p'(t)=X\Big(\phi_p\big(h_p(t)\big)\Big)\cdot h_p'(t)=f(\psi_p(t)) \cdot X(\psi_p(t))$$

So if $ X(\psi_p(t)) \neq 0$, this forces $h_p'(t)=f(\psi_p(t))=f\Big(\phi_p\big(h_p(t)\big)\Big)$

This motivates we try to analyze the following equation, $\forall p \in M$:

$$(2) \,\, h_p(0)=0,h_p'(t)=f\Big(\phi_p\big(h_p(t)\big)\Big)$$

**We now change notations:**

Define $h:\R \times M \to \R$ via: $h(t,p)=h_p(t)$.
Denote $\til M = \R \times M$, and consider the hypersurface $S = \{0\} \times M \subseteq \til M$.
 then $(2)$ becomes:

$$(3) \, \, h|_S=0, \pd{}{t} h = (f \circ \phi) \big(h(t,p),p\big)$$

The vector field $\pd{}{t} \in \Ga\brk{T \til \M}$ is nowhere tangent to $S$ (since $T_{\brk{0,p}}S=0 \oplus T_p\M$ and $\pd{}{t}(t,p)=(1,0)$).

Denote $C^\infty\brk{\til M \times \R} \ni \til f: \til M \times \R \to \R$ via the formula:

$$\til f((t,p),s) = (f \circ \phi)(s,p) $$, then $(3)$ becomes:

$$ (4) \, \,  h|_S=0, \pd{}{t} h = \til f \big((t,p),h(t,p)\big)$$

The above equation is an instance of a **Quasilinear Cauchy problem** (on the manifold $\til M$), so we know $\forall \til p=(0,p) \in S$ there exists a unique solution in some neighbourhood $U$ of $\til p$.

(See for instance Theorem 9.53, page 242 in John M.Lee's book "Introduction to smooth manifolds")

In the case $M$ is compact, we can proceed in the following way:

$\forall p \in \M , (0,p) \in S \Rightarrow  (0,p) \in U \Rightarrow$ there exists an open set $\til U_p \subseteq U$ which contains $(0,p)$. Hence, there exists $\ep_p \in \R \, , \, U_p \subseteq \M$ ($U_p$ open in $\M$)  such that $(-\ep_p,\ep_p) \times U_p \subseteq \til U_p$. $\{U_p|p \in \M\}$ form an open cover of $\M$, hence (**by compactness of $M$**) there is a finite subcover $U_{p_1},\dots ,  U_{p_n}$.

Define $\ep = min\{\ep_{p_i}|i=1,\dots,n \}$. It follows immediately that $(-\ep,\ep) \times \M \subseteq U$.

**So, we have stablished exsitence of a unique solution on $(-\ep,\ep) \times \M$.**

**The problem is how to continue from here.**

A naive approach is to define
 $X = \{t \in I| \text{there exists a unique solution for $(4)$ in  } (-t,t) \times \M \}$.

Look at $s= \text{sup} X$. We claim $\text{sup} X \in X$. Since $X$ is *closed downward*, i.e :  $x \in X \Rightarrow \brk{0 \le x' < x \Rightarrow x' \in X}$ it follows that $[0,s) \subseteq X$.

It's easy to see there must be a unique solution for $(4)$ on $(-s,s) \times \M$. (If there were two different solutions, they would differ already at some $s'<s$ which contradicts $[0,s) \subseteq X$).

Hence, by continuity, there is **at most one** solution on $[-s,s] \times \M$.

So, **if we knew it's possibe to extend** the unique solution on $(-s,s) \times \M$ to $[-s,s] \times \M$, then we could advance the (existence and) uniqueness further, via the same argument, thus obtaining a contradiction.

(In that case our initial hypersurfaces would have been $\{s\} \times M$,$\{-s\} \times M$).

I am not sure how to show the solution can be extended that way.

In principle, we can also start the equation from $t=s$ by requiring $h(s,p)$ to satisfy $\psi(s,p)=\phi(h(s,p),p)$. Since non-constant integral curves are injective or periodic, we this might  determine $h_{\{s\} \times M}$ uniquely and perhaps we can continue from there.
(Although then the issue of smoothness arise).

Comment: Note that in general the solution may explode (although not on compact manifolds). On noncompact manifolds it may happen in general that some  trajectories reach infinity in finite time, that's all that can change with your reparametrization. PS: I was going to ask about the sign of $f$ before you changed it.

Comment: Your reparametrizarion is in fact crucial in several topics of dynamical systems, since it is one of the best ways to spoil the *uniformity* of hyperbolicity.

Answer (score 11):

For general (and in particular, noncompact) manifolds this is false:

**Hint** Consider the standard coordinate vector field $$X := \partial_x$$ on $\Bbb R$, which is complete (its flow is $(t, a) \to a + t$, which in particular is defined on all of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$), and take $$f(x) := 1 + x^2 . $$

> Then, substituting in the definition gives that the flow curve $\psi_0(t)$ of $f X$ starting at the origin is the solution to the i.v.p. $$\psi_0'(t) = \left[1 + \psi_0(t)^2\right] \partial_x, \qquad \psi_0(0) = 0.$$ Writing the sole component in the global frame $(\partial_x)$, applying the Method of Separation by Variables, and carrying out a straightforward integration gives that the flow curve is $$\psi_0(t) = \tan t, \qquad -\tfrac{\pi}{2} < t < \tfrac{\pi}{2},$$ which in particular cannot be extended even continuously outside this interval. So, $f X$ is not complete.

Of course, any smoothly rescaled smooth vector field $f X$ is still smooth, so its flow $\psi_a(t)$ starting at any point $a$ exists for some finite interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, and it shouldn't be too much work to write down a reasonably explicit lower bound for $\epsilon$ for any $\delta > 0$ in terms of $\delta$ and an upper bound for $|f|$ on $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ (and, to be clear, on $a$).

On the other hand, the conjecture in the question is true if we add one of two simple hypotheses: It follows from the dramatic-sounding *Escape Lemma* that if $X$ is complete and

- $|f|$ is bounded and/or
- $M$ is compact,

then $f X$ is complete. (In this latter case, this is for the simple reason that any smooth vector field on a compact manifold is complete.)

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would explain their objection?

Comment: Thanks for your solution (I upvoted). I still wonder about the compact case, is there actually a unique global smoothly changing reparametrization $h:\mathbb{R} \times M \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $\psi(t,p)=\phi(h(t,p),p) \forall t \in \mathbb{R} , p \in M$? I know that if there is such a reparametrization than it's unique, but I failed to show there exists a *global* one...

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but I think the answer must be yes: This is an ODE in $h(\cdot, p)$ (for each $p$ separately), so one is guaranteed a solution, and a blowup of this solution would correspond to a blowup of some integral curve, which cannot happen for $M$ compact. This leaves remaining just smoothness of $h$ as a function of $(t, p)$, but I think this follows from a general result about smoothness of solutions under (smooth) variations of initial conditions. As I recall, this is treated in some detail in the text of Lee you mention.

Comment: In a sense you are right. However, I think there still might be a slight delicacy concerning the issue of initial conditions. We know how to give them at time $t=0$, but on other times I am not sure how can we specify them exactly... (I am not sure I am making myself clear about my concern , I will try to write a more detailed explanation of the problem I see here later)

Comment: No, I don't quite see what you mean, but there are certainly some modest delicacies in this setup.

Comment: @TravisWillse Is there an easy way (in the non-compact case) to see that $fX$ is still complete whenever $|f|$ is bounded from the escape lemma? It is clear to me the fact that any vector fields on a compact smooth manifold is complete follows directly from the aforementioned lemma, but not the other case. Thank you!